# Не отправляется запрос на сервер

Tags: javascript, сервер, запрос

Не получается отправить `post` запрос. Текст ошибки:

*Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://localhost:8080/lambdas. (Причина: неудача канала CORS preflight).*

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Политика браузеров запрещающая кросс доменные запросы (а также на другой порт)

Comment: то есть проблема не в сервере?

Comment: Ну в общем нет, это просто ограничение браузера в целях безопасности попробуйте слать с данными на http://localhost:8080 заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteскоторогоделаетсязапрос.com`

Comment: извиняюсь, я таким впервые занимаюсь) как добавить заголовок?

Comment: серверная часть на php?

Comment: на java........

Comment: было бы nodejs или php то помог а так не шарю в JAVA

Comment: последнее уточнение) нужно в запросе что-то поменять, чтобы этот запрет обойти или все-таки на сервере?

Comment: Да надо прописать чтобы сервер слал заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin с доменом с которого делается запрос на который делается запрос `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteскоторогоделаетсязапрос.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все дело в том что кросс доменные запросы запрещены в целях безопасности, но если все же нужно сделать такой запрос, то требуется чтобы сервер на который делается запрос с данными, отправлял дополнительный заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, тем самым разрешая такие запросы к нему, подробно прочитать можно [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)

Comment: вроде добавил, не помогло( может, еще что-то нужно?

Comment: Должно было помочь проверьте в браузере  отправляет ли заголовок

Comment: да, отправляет, но post почему-то заменяется на options

Comment: Думаю поможет ссылка https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B а исходя из http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript-jquery/thread1865586.html похоже что возможно дело в сервере